# Do you have to physically collect the coins?

Tags: pokemon-rumble-world

I've noticed that if you don't collect the coins before they disappear your total coin count increases as soon as it's gone.  Is there any benefit to going out of your way to collect the coins then?  If not, then the vacuum upgrade seems worthless.

Comment: Note that if you leave an area before you collect `P`, it will **not** be added to your total.

Comment: I also think that coins are only collected if they're still on your screen when they disappear. If you move too far away from them, they won't be added to your total

Comment: @Pyritie I have seen my total go up after leaving some `P` out of the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main advantage is keeping your **Combo** going.  Your combo meter increases when you attack a Pokémon and is extended as long as you damage Pokémon or pick up collectables like `P` and `health-up` powerups.  Since you get big bonus `P` drops every 10 combos (with a giant bonus at 50), extending your combo is crucial between waves of enemies.

This can be done by grabbing the `P` dropped by the Pokémon you fought while you walk to the next area with more Pokémon.  If you have vacuum upgrades, you can drag several of these behind you as you head to a new area, making it more likely that you'll be able to keep your combo going until you get to the next area with Pokémon.  (Granted, it's unlikely that the bonus that you get from your extended combos will ever pay off the thousands of `P` it costs to buy the upgrade, but hey... what else are you gonna spend the `P` on?)